# Jquery Based Calculator Issue

Tags: jquery

Right now I am working on a interesting price calculator for a site.
You can see the working demo here http://demo.coregenie.com/Greenboxx/ 
Check the button for price calculator.

Each button on top have its own features selection button below it.
If a user clicks on the Boxx1 he will see the next selection which is length of the video presentation. Each length have a price predefined. If user selects a option this will add into the price total at bottom. This is working.

The issues I am facing is: Now a user is able to select multiple BOXX Option ( Light of video) I don't need this. ( I have made the deactivate option of the button colour  using a class switch so only one selection is visible)
Can any one tell me what the issue?

My js is Here:
http://demo.coregenie.com/Greenboxx/wp-content/themes/Greenbox/calc.js

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on the boxx4 button you should hide the other buttons (as you do with boxx1, boxx2 and boxx3). Something like this should work:

```
$('#box_four_area_click').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('button_four_active');
     $('#box_one_area_click').removeClass('button_one_active');
     $('#box_two_area_click').removeClass('button_two_active');
     $('#box_three_area_click').removeClass('button_three_active');

     // Hide other buttons
     $('#box_one_area').hide();
     $('#box_one_area_features').hide();
     $('#box_two_area').hide();
     $('#box_two_area_features').hide();
     $('#box_three_area').hide();
     $('#box_three_area_features').hide();
});
```

Comment: Hiding issue is not main. Main issue is it calculate old value to my total. If i select a vale in boxx1 option and then select boxx2 option and set a value now i have to calculate it from zero i set the value 0 one click but while i select a option the value also add with my old (boxx1) selected value! this my main issue

Comment: Please consider editing your question and adding further explanations of your problem (and what you want to achieve).